# Following a TensorFlow tutorial and am not getting accurate model predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am following a [tutorial on TensorFlow image classifications](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-steps-to-build-your-first-image-classifier-with-code-cf244b015799).

My use case differs slightly from the tutorial, it uses Chess pieces, whereas I am using traffic lights, and want to detect if its red, green or amber.

I am finding that the results of my tests are poor,and wonder if it is to do with the `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` I see in the CreateData section of the tutorial. Of course colour matters in my classifier, so I wonder if the tutorial is converting to greyscale, hence my lack of accurate results.

I therefore changed all references of `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` to `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`, reran the CreateData routines, then tried to run the NeuralNetwork creation program, but that then fails with error:

```
  File "CreateNeuralNetwork.py", line 54, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_split=0.1)
  File "/Users/stuff/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 709, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/Users/stuff/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2688, in _standardize_user_data
    training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/Users/stuff/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 483, in check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 195 input samples and 65 target samples.
```

I am guessing this has changed the size / complexity of my network and thus something is now wrong in the network creation, can anybody help me track where that would be(I have no changed any part of it from the blog post I linked to above).

I bet there is changes needed in this bit:

```
# normalizing data (a pixel goes from 0 to 255)
X = X/255.0

# Building the model
model = Sequential()

# 3 convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

Given that a pixel in grayscale would be 0 to 255, but a colour pixel would be a lot more than that, and more likely to be a RGB vector. I am not sure where to go , or what to change.

I may be way of track, thoughts would be appreciated.

Additionally, when training the model with the line:

```
history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_split=0.1)
```

it seems epochs is how many times to train the model. Is there an advantage to doing this 400 times over 40? Will these other parameters be of importance? How will I know if I have 'overtrained' the model? What is the tipping point?

Comment: You risk over training if you use too many epochs but this will most likely not occur if you use 400 epochs versus 40, unless your data set is small; i am guessing. It looks like the images in the link you provided are in fact greyscale and if your images are RGB then you want to adjust for this.

Comment: Please see an update to my question

Comment: Can you add a few data samples? the issues usually cames from the data.
As for the shape error, I believe this line is an issue (line 53 from blog post above), just change the last 1 to 3 `X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the error shows that it is treating each channel of a color image as a separate greyscale image. That's why "Found 195 input samples and 65 target samples" i.e 3 times more. So, you should look in the code where data is prepared. Check line 53

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

You should change this to

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

Hope this helps.

Regarding your second question "How will I know if I have 'overtrained' the model? What is the tipping point?"

Plot the accuracy and loss graph and this will give you an idea about the bias and variance. For the setting of the epochs parameter, Keras callbacks can come handy. With this you can monitor any quantity like train_loss, train_acc, etc. and if it's not increasing you can automatically stop fitting the model further.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: What about the line X = X /255.0?

Comment: This is done to normalize the pixel values to a range between 0 and 1. Doing so speeds up the training.

Comment: But would this need altered for colour against grayscale in my implementation?

Comment: What does the IMG_SIZE represent, what would 50 be? A 50 x 50 square? My images are all different sizes so I need this to be flexible.